# Where to ask "Why Derby"?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

[Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/). I need to ask a question from one sentences:

> Why, or when, do I use
>   [Derby](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/derby/info) while we have other many RDBMS such as MySQL, postgreSQL, etc?

I'm afraid to ask this question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) in order to be off-topic. I have tried to search for any article to offer direct answer but I could not able to find any.

Generally, Where on the Stack Exchange Network to ask about "why to using X technology?"

Comment: I'd try in chat.  Also, the tag has its own list of the high points.  I suppose if those don't win you over from MySQL or postgre, you have your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You generally don't ask such questions on the Stack Exchange network.

This is a classic "poll", there isn't a conclusively right answer to this, but a lot of opinion.

This kind of question that cannot have an objectively right answer - which simply doesn't work for how Stack Exchange sites operate (where we expect an objectively best answer to be possible).

Comment: You are right, but for every technology, there are listing for pros & cons or why did it be introduced, or what are the solutions it meant by. In most cases these topics are covered in the technology documentation and definitions. However, this point is not found for some others such as Derby.

Comment: Be that as it may, Stack Exchange sites are not the place for them. Perhaps Documentation on Stack Overflow would become such a place, but currently and particularly the Q&A side of the sites isn't.